# Need ideas for php array

Tags: arrays, merge

I have multi array.

Ex:

```
$array1 = array("0",.. , "1000");
$array2 = array("0",.. , "1000");
$array3 = array("0",.. , "1000");
.....
$arrayN = array("0",.. , "1000");
```

I need merge all array to result:

```
$array_result = $array1[0]..$array1[100] + $array2[0]..$array2[100] + .. + $arrayN[0] .. $arrayN[100] + $array1[101]..$array1[200] + $array2[101]..$array2[200] + .. + $arrayN[101]..$arrayN[200] + ...
```

Comment: Actually what ideas you need?

Comment: if you want to just merge array you can use array_merge() function and if you want sum of array values you can use array_sum() function

Comment: i need, print_r($array_result) output: Array
(
[0] => $array1[0] //value array1
[1] => $array1[1] //value array1
...
[100] => $array1[100] //value array1
[101] => $array2[0] //value array2
[102] => $array2[1] //value array2
...
[200] => $array2[100] //value array2
...
// loop
[N] => $array1[101] //value array1
[N+1] => $array1[102] //value array1
...
[M] => $array2[101] //value array2
[M+1] => $array2[102] //value array1
...
)

Answer (score 0):

There is predefined PHP function to merge arrays. Which works something like this:

```
$array1 = array(1, 2);
$array2 = array("a", "b");
$result = array_merge($array1, $array2);
```

Please refer to following manual on PHP: 
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

Or if you simply want to append array elements this should work fine:

```
$result = $array1 + $array2;
```

Comment: I need output
Array ( 
[0] => $array1[0] //value array1 
[1] => $array1[1] //value array1 
... 
[100] => $array1[100] //value array1 
[101] => $array2[0] //value array2 
[102] => $array2[1] //value array2 
... 
[200] => $array2[100] //value array2 
... 
// loop 
[N] => $array1[101] //value array1 
[N+1] => $array1[102] //value array1 
... 
[M] => $array2[101] //value array2 
[M+1] => $array2[102] //value array1 
... 
)